# How to prevent upowerd from being launched

Tags: services, power-management, d-bus, plasma

Running DM-Less KDE-Plasma-5.19.5 Under a non-systemd Linux-5.4.80 and dbus-1.12.20

I try to get rid of the upowerd daemon.

I understand that upowerd is launched by dbus upon request from whatever other service / application.

powerdevil (5.19.5) being the first culprit I thought about, I started disabling it (The canonical way i.e. pushing "Hidden=true" in associated .desktop file.)

The associated powerdevil daemon no longer starts at session startup... and no longer shows in ps.
However... upowerd is still launched.

So, what is (are) that (these) services (other than powerdevil) requesting dbus to launch upowerd ?
Or, at least, how can I find it (them) ?

---

BTW 1 : qdbus does not help. (Or I did not manage to find how it can help)

BTW 2 : I did consider other threads here around instructing how to prevent upowerd to run. However, 1/ the environments differ and 2/ I do not want to immediately prevent upowerd to start. I'd prefer instead, (as I already did with powerdevil) prevent the launch of the services requesting dbus to launch upowerd.

---

**UPDATE 1 :** From the reading of the Xserver man page, I had thought that the DMPS extension (loaded by default) of the Xserver made it the perfect culprit :
Alas... in vain, I disabled the DPMS extension ( verified it is actually reported disabled in Xorg.log ) however... upowerd is still launched at session startup.

---

Just in case it would help... helping me, I paste hereafter qdbus' output

```
:
:1.1
:1.10
 org.kde.KWin
:1.11
 org.kde.ActivityManager
:1.112
 org.kde.kiod5
 org.kde.kioexecd
 org.kde.kpasswdserver
 org.kde.kssld5
:1.12
 org.kde.kglobalaccel
:1.121
 org.kde.konsole-18273
:1.122
:1.13
 org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver
 org.kde.ksmserver
 org.kde.screensaver
:1.14
:1.15
 org.kde.kaccess
:1.16
 org.kde.polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1
:1.18
 org.freedesktop.Notifications
 org.kde.JobViewServer
 org.kde.StatusNotifierHost-3379
 org.kde.klipper
 org.kde.kuiserver
 org.kde.plasmashell
:1.19
:1.20
 com.canonical.Unity
 org.kde.lattedock
:1.21
 com.hplip.StatusService
:1.22
:1.23
 org.kde.KScreen
:1.24
:1.32
 org.kio5.kio_http_cache_cleaner
:1.38
 org.kde.kwalletd5
:1.5
 org.kde.klauncher5
:1.54
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Control
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Control.lock
:1.56
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Janitor
:1.57
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_akonotes_resource_0
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Resource.akonadi_akonotes_resource_0
:1.58
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_contacts_resource_0
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Resource.akonadi_contacts_resource_0
:1.59
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_birthdays_resource
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Resource.akonadi_birthdays_resource
:1.60
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_followupreminder_agent
:1.61
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_ical_resource_0
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Resource.akonadi_ical_resource_0
:1.62
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_indexing_agent
:1.63
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_newmailnotifier_agent
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.NewMailNotifierAgent
:1.64
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_maildispatcher_agent
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.MailDispatcherAgent
:1.65
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_pop3_resource_1
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Resource.akonadi_pop3_resource_1
:1.66
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_maildir_resource_0
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Resource.akonadi_maildir_resource_0
:1.67
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_migration_agent
:1.68
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_pop3_resource_0
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Resource.akonadi_pop3_resource_0
:1.69
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_sendlater_agent
:1.7
 org.kde.GtkConfig
 org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher
 org.kde.kappmenu
 org.kde.kcookiejar5
 org.kde.kded5
 org.kde.keyboard
 org.kde.kscreen.osdService
:1.70
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_archivemail_agent
:1.71
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_unifiedmailbox_agent
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Resource.akonadi_unifiedmailbox_agent
:1.72
 org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Agent.akonadi_mailfilter_agent
:1.8
:1.84
:1.86
:1.88
:1.89
 org.kde.kate-11242
:1.9
 ca.desrt.dconf
org.freedesktop.DBus
```

Comment: If you don't want it to run can't you simply remove it?

Comment: And you need `qdbus --system` to list upower

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk : Of course I can simply remove it! Deny everything in associated /usr/share/dbus... entry Pfiutt! Gone! However... this might well break another service / process that I do (or do not) care a damn about. Therefore I would first prefer to know what are these services requesting upowered to be launched in order to disable them (or not) first.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk : BTW, you are correct. qdbus --system will actually show UPower... but... won't tell me who requested it.